# How to combine 'like' elements within nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, sequence

I have `3` nested lists:

```
STEP = [['S', '1', 'B', '3'], ['S', '3', 'B', '11'], ['S', '5', 'B', '12'], ['S', '4', 'B', '13'], ['S', '2', 'B', '14']]

TRANSITION = [['T', '2', 'B', '4'], ['T', '7', 'B', '4'], ['T', '3', 'S', '4'], ['T', '5', 'S', '5'], ['T', '1', 'S', '2'], ['T', '8', 'S', '2'], ['T', '6', 'S', '1'], ['T', '9', 'S', '2'], ['T', '4', 'S', '1'], ['T', '10', 'S', '1']]

BRANCH = [['B', '3', 'T', '1'], ['B', '3', 'T', '7'], ['B', '4', 'S', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '5'], ['B', '12', 'T', '6'], ['B', '12', 'T', '8'], ['B', '13', 'T', '4'], ['B', '13', 'T', '9'], ['B', '14', 'T', '2'], ['B', '14', 'T', '10']]
```

Each element holds information as such:

```
# Example

STEP[0]  =  ['S', '1', 'B', '3']
```

*Where:*

- 'S' is the `STEP` type
- '1' is the `STEP` number id
- 'B' is the linked `BRANCH` type
- '3' is the linked `BRANCH` number id

Starting from a `STEP` the data is all linked, so using the linked reference you can find the next element and the next until another `STEP` is reached.

*This is some parameters of the data:*

- `STEPS` are connected to single `BRANCHES`
- `BRANCHES` are connected to one or more `TRANSITIONS`
- `TRANSITIONS` can be connected to a single `BRANCH` or `STEP`

The `BRANCH` data can have a fork where a single `BRANCH` id has one or more options for `TRANSITIONS`.

I would like to combine these forks to the same `BRANCH' id, ie:

```
# BRANCH[0] and BRANCH[1] both have an id of '3' 
# therefore, need to be combined

BRANCH[0] = ['B', '3', 'T', ['1', '7']]
```

This should be done to create a new list that combines all 'like' `BRANCHES`.

### My attempt thus far (did not get very far):

```
    for i in B:
        if i[1] == B['all except current i'][1]
            # append the branch id and the two transitions
```

Comment: so far what you have tried ?

Comment: I have tried for loops that try to check if the current branch selected matches any of the other branches in terms of linked transition number. Then if they do to append them together to a single branch id. This keeps hitting roadblocks.

Comment: can you add in your code here, so that will be a good starting point for others to help you

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll update the Question with what I have so far

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there are easier ways, but based on your example, you can try :

```
BRANCH = [['B', '3', 'T', '1'], ['B', '3', 'T', '7'], ['B', '4', 'S', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', '5'], ['B', '12', 'T', '6'], ['B', '12', 'T', '8'], ['B', '13', 'T', '4'], ['B', '13', 'T', '9'], ['B', '14', 'T', '2'], ['B', '14', 'T', '10']]
tmp = {}
final = []
for x in BRANCH:
    if not f"{x[0]}-{x[1]}" in tmp:
        tmp[f"{x[0]}-{x[1]}"] = [x[3]]
    else:
        tmp[f"{x[0]}-{x[1]}"].append(x[3])

for k, v in tmp.items():
    one, two = k.split("-")
    for x in BRANCH:
        if x[0] == one and x[1] == two:
            if not [one, two, x[2], v] in final:
                final.append([one, two, x[2], v])

print(final)
```

---

```
[['B', '3', 'T', ['1', '7']], ['B', '4', 'S', ['3']], ['B', '11', 'T', ['3', '5']], ['B', '12', 'T', ['6', '8']], ['B', '13', 'T', ['4', '9']], ['B', '14', 'T', ['2', '10']]]
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/5d9f0c7805)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a test for similarity of the branches and then loop over the branches checking similarity.  The rest is just guarding against duplicates and massaging the data to a list of lists.  I did randomize the data and add another item to check that it wouldn't choke on more than a pair of similar branches.

```
# Check similarity (first three fields equal).
def similar_p(one, two):
    for item in range(len(one) - 1):
        if one[item] != two[item]:
            return False
    return True

# Data.  Works sorted and not.
branches = [
    ['B', '14', 'T', '2'],
    ['B', '12', 'T', '6'],
    ['B', '14', 'T', '10'],
    ['B', '13', 'T', '4'],
    ['B', '3', 'T', '9'],
    ['B', '12', 'T', '8'],
    ['B', '13', 'T', '9'],
    ['B', '3', 'T', '7'],
    ['B', '4', 'S', '3'],
    ['B', '11', 'T', '5'],
    ['B', '3', 'T', '1'],
    ['B', '11', 'T', '3'],
    ]

merge_dict = {}

# Loop over branches.  Uncomment print statements to watch the action.
for i in range(len(branches)):
    # print('check for similars to branch {}'.format(branches[i]))
    # try/except to ensure the dictionary item is actually there.
    try:
        # print(merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])])
        if branches[i][3] not in merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])]:
            merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])].append(branches[i][3])
            # print('initial appending to branch {}'.format(branches[i]))
    except (KeyError):
        merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])] = [branches[i][3]]
        # print('starting branch {}'.format(branches[i]))
    for j in range((i + 1), len(branches), 1):
        if similar_p(branches[i], branches[j]):
            if branches[j][3] not in merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])]:
                merge_dict[tuple(branches[i][0:3])].append(branches[j][3])
                # print('appending similar branch {} to branch {}'.format(branches[j], branches[i]))

merged = list()

# Massage into a list.  Sorting is on you, kid.
for k,v in merge_dict.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        merged.append([*k, *v])
    else:
        merged.append([*k, v])

print(merged)
```

Output:

```
[['B', '14', 'T', ['2', '10']], ['B', '12', 'T', ['6', '8']], ['B', '13', 'T', ['4', '9']], ['B', '3', 'T', ['9', '7', '1']], ['B', '4', 'S', '3'], ['B', '11', 'T', ['5', '3']]]
```